# Pass DropDown value to RelayCommand in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

This is my Code in XAML.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ></telerik:RadComboBox>

<telerik:RadButton Name="BtnExportToPdf" Content="Export To PDF" Command="{Binding ExportToPDFClickCommand}"></telerik:RadButton>
```

Below is my RelayCommand in ViewModel

```
public ICommand ExportToPdfClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(ExportReportData);
        }
    }
```

I want to pass Dropdown Value to Relay Command. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need to pass the selected item to your command?
Your viewmodel already has that value:

SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"

As a result, just refrence your SelectedItem property within your view-model.